# With a button, ask a prompt, show the answer and save it for later

Tags: javascript, button, prompt

I have a button that will show  a prompt  and ask for answer when clicked  and shows the answer directly at the place  where the button was. But I also want to save this answer to re-use it later.

Here is what I have for now:

```
My name is <button onclick="this.outerHTML = prompt('What is your name?');">your name</button> .
```

How can I do that? Thx a lot for your help.

EDIT: I am gonna be more explicit.

I have a long text. Inside this text, I have made buttons which prompts questions. I want the answers of those prompts to replace those buttons. And I also want to be able to use the answers of those prompts later in my text.

I made this little function:

```
function question() {
    var pprenom1 = prompt('Your name?');
    return pprenom1;
}
```

And this in the HTML:

```
My name is <button onclick="this.outerHTML = question('pprenom1');">What is your name?</button>, a cool name.
```

And I want to be able to use the result of "pprenom1" later in my text. 
And I will also have many more buttons/questions like that.
Thx again.

Answer (score 0):

```
function foo() {
   var aswer = prompt('Whats your name?');
   document.getElementById('show-div').innerHTML = aswer;
}

<button onclick="foo()" />
<div id="show-div"></div>
```

I dont know if I understand our correctly, but this call a prompt after click button, and save the name into the div.

EDIT:

Then I think this solve your problem, you need to declare var outside of functions an you can access from all functions, like this:

```
<html>
...

<script>

var param1;

function foo() {
   var aswer = prompt('Whats your name?');
    param1 = aswer;
}

</script>

...
</html>
```

Comment: thx but it's not exactly what i want to do. I edited my question to be more explicit.

Comment: @user2094538 I eddited my aswer, check if this solve your problem, best regards.